# printing out file if columns from two files match

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two files one looks like this,

```
chrom   start   end ref alt alt_freq_CR alt_freq_ID gene    gene_type
chr10   28814618    28814618    T   C   0   0.4167  AAA sense
chr10   32557818    32557818    C   T   0   0.1579  BBB PC
chr10   119245101   119245101   T   C   0   0.1667  ZZZ rega
chr10   119245101   119245101   T   C   0   0.1667  CCC sense
```

file 2

```
   chrom    start   end ref alt alt_freq_CR alt_freq_ID gene      gene_type
chr10   28814618    28814618    T   C   0   0.4167  AAA sense
chr10   32557   32557   C   T   0   0.1579  BBB PC
chr10   119245101   119245101   T   C   0   0.1667  DDD rega
chr10   119245101   119245101   T   C   0   0.1667  EEE sense
```

I need a output file, if it satisfies following conditions as,
if the column (8th column) gene from file_1 and gene (8th column) from file_2 are matching then it it should print out as following,

```
chrom   start   end ref alt alt_freq_CR alt_freq_ID gene    gene_type   chrom   start   end ref alt alt_freq_CR alt_freq_ID
chr10   28814618    28814618    T   C   0   0.4167  AAA sense   chr10   28814618    28814618    T   C   0   0.4167
chr10   32557818    32557818    C   T   0   0.1579  BBB PC  chr10   32557   32557   C   T   0   0.1579
```

I tried using awk for this as following but it didn't print all the matching rows in output..

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$16]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$16]){print b}}' file_1 file_2
```

It would be really great if there is a solution in python script, Also The two files are of different size , interms of number of rows are different .

Comment: you may want to read the chapters in pandas docs about `merge` and `join`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
index = df1.icol(7) == df2.icol(7)
df = pd.concat((df1[index], df2[index]), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Actually my two files is of different length and so with the above script , I have the following error message, Series lengths must match to compare

Comment: I see. The above method assumes that the tables are aligned; otherwise, the matching is not well defined (either there isn't a one-to-one correspondence between records or you get different matches based on sorting order). If records are aligned, you can truncate each table by minimal length of the two; if no alignment is assumed, you should look at `join` method.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `pandas.merge`. Read your files into Pandas with `pandas.read_csv` and join on the `'gene'` column. Here's the solution to your example.

```
In [9]: df1
Out[9]:
   chrom      start        end ref alt  alt_freq_CR  alt_freq_ID gene  \
0  chr10   28814618   28814618   T   C            0       0.4167  AAA
1  chr10   32557818   32557818   C   T            0       0.1579  BBB
2  chr10  119245101  119245101   T   C            0       0.1667  ZZZ
3  chr10  119245101  119245101   T   C            0       0.1667  CCC

  gene_type
0     sense
1        PC
2      rega
3     sense

In [10]: df2
Out[10]:
   chrom      start        end ref alt  alt_freq_CR  alt_freq_ID gene  \
0  chr10   28814618   28814618   T   C            0       0.4167  AAA
1  chr10      32557      32557   C   T            0       0.1579  BBB
2  chr10  119245101  119245101   T   C            0       0.1667  DDD
3  chr10  119245101  119245101   T   C            0       0.1667  EEE

  gene_type
0     sense
1        PC
2      rega
3     sense

In [11]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='gene')
Out[11]:
  chrom_x   start_x     end_x ref_x alt_x  alt_freq_CR_x  alt_freq_ID_x gene  \
0   chr10  28814618  28814618     T     C              0         0.4167  AAA
1   chr10  32557818  32557818     C     T              0         0.1579  BBB

  gene_type_x chrom_y   start_y     end_y ref_y alt_y  alt_freq_CR_y  \
0       sense   chr10  28814618  28814618     T     C              0
1          PC   chr10     32557     32557     C     T              0

   alt_freq_ID_y gene_type_y
0         0.4167       sense
1         0.1579          PC
```

As you can see, this operation adds a suffix to columns that share the same name between the two DataFrames. A suffix is required, but you can change the suffix with the `suffixes` keyword argument:

```
In [14]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='gene', suffixes=['_df1', '_df2'])
Out[14]:
  chrom_df1  start_df1   end_df1 ref_df1 alt_df1  alt_freq_CR_df1  \
0     chr10   28814618  28814618       T       C                0
1     chr10   32557818  32557818       C       T                0

   alt_freq_ID_df1 gene gene_type_df1 chrom_df2  start_df2   end_df2 ref_df2  \
0           0.4167  AAA         sense     chr10   28814618  28814618       T
1           0.1579  BBB            PC     chr10      32557     32557       C

  alt_df2  alt_freq_CR_df2  alt_freq_ID_df2 gene_type_df2
0       C                0           0.4167         sense
1       T                0           0.1579            PC
```

Pandas has an exhaustive guide to [merging](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) in its documentation.